# One to Many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `Task` entity like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int  TaskOwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual EPDUser TaskOwner { get; set; }

    public virtual List<EPDUser> TaskOwners { get; set; }
 }
```

And `EPDUser` entity is

```
public class EPDUser
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is, I am just maintaining `TaskOwners` who has held this task before (like history of reassign), that's why I have a list inside the `Task` entity, and the `TaskOwnerId` property holds current task owner id.

I am trying to create a new mapping table like below,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
            .HasMany(x => x.TaskOwners)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("TaskId")
                       .MapRightKey("TaskOwnerId")
                       .ToTable("TaskOwnerHistory"));
```

I got this error when tried to update my database.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.TaskOwnerHistory_dbo.EPDUsers_TaskOwnerId' on table 'TaskOwnerHistory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Kinldy help me to store the list of taskowners as history.

Comment: The HasMany().WithMany() is used to create many-to-many relationship. Aren't you missing something in the WithMany() clause?

Comment: @Gimly, Thanks for your reply. I have mentioned that line
`modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasOptional(x => x.TaskOwners).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`  but still am getting the same error. :(

Comment: Yes, but the WithMany clause is there to define the other side of a Many to many relationship. You could have for example `WithMany(x => x.OwnedTasks)`. Leaving it empty seems a bit weird to me and might be the cause.

Comment: but, I don't have a Tasks collection in EPDUser table. Anyhow, I just want to store the task ownership change history. Ca n you please suggest me a good approach??

Comment: Did you try removing the `WithMany()` clause? What do you expect your schema to be? A table with just the list of previous owners ID?

Comment: Yes Gimly, I just want to keep the list of TaskOwnersId of a particular Task.

Comment: WithMany() is perfectly fine. Just means that you don't want to navigate from there.

Comment: Hi Alex, No luck, I am getting the same Foreign key error.

Comment: I got the reason, why this error occured. I have a EPDUser single object and EPDUser entity as List in Task. The problem got resolved when I removed the EPDUser single object from Task.but I want to keep the current owner of task and history. If i removed that single object, I can't get the current task owner